# Three.js Post Processing SMAA

Tags: javascript, three.js, post-processing

I am trying to implement SMAA into a Three.js project using the PostProcessing.js library (https://github.com/vanruesc/postprocessing) however;, I am having trouble doing so. As I understand it, since you use the effect composer to add render passes to the scene post-process, you cannot use the built-in WebGL anti-aliasing.

I have an SMAA object set up that appears to work properly, but there is still aliasing around the edges of the cube I am using for testing purposes.

[image]

In the console, an error and a warning are being printed:

"three.min.js:2 THREE.WebGLState: TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': Overload resolution failed"

"three.min.js:2 THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for an update, but the image is undefined."

If I had to guess, I would say I need some SMAA image file to map onto the scene?

Appreciate any help.